# Laravel Cloning Model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-9

Have a Default Settings model like this

```
Facility DefaultSettings
     id = 1,start_time = 07:00 PM,close_Time = 06:00 AM
```

It has a Relation

```
Employees
    id=1, facility_set_id = 1 ,name = John,
    id=2, facility_set_id = 1 ,name = Mike,
```

And then a FACILITY model

```
    id,start_time,close_Time
```

Which has same relation

```
 Employees
    id, facility_set_id,name
```

The goal is to clone from Facility DefaultSettings into the Facility.

Any ideeas?

Help will be appreciated!
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
$defaultFacility = FacilityDefaultSettings::first();
$facility = new Facility($defaultFacility->toArray());
```

You can also set the `$attributes` property on the model like

```
class Facility extends Model
{
    protected $attributes = [
        'start_time' => '07:00 PM',
        ...
    ];
    ...
```

These attributes will be filled by default with the values specified when you create the model